# Node Js Http request response to Angular website,

Tags: node.js, angular, http, get

I am currently creating a website to work alongside a Nodejs server that I am running and hosting using Ngrok(will be deployed to Google cloud if I want to host it online). I am currently working on using HTTP requests to communicate with the webservice and I am having some trouble with getting a response from the service.

The following code is currently being used on my NodeJs server to listen for incoming requests:

```javascript
    app.get("/makeUser",function(request, response){
        console.log(request.query.email+"  "+request.query.name);
        var email = request.query.email;
        var uid = request.query.name;
        response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        if(request.query.email)
        {
            PerformQuery("INSERT INTO Users(Key_Value,Cellphone_number,Email) VALUES('"+uid+"', 'test-number','"+email+"')")
            response.send(({
                message: 'User registered'
            }));
        }
        else
        {
           console.log("Error creatimg user")
        }
    });
```

This will handle any get requests to create a new User. In my website that is created in the Angular framework I have the following code that will send the request:

```javascript
     SignUp(email, password) {
        return this.afAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
          .then(async (result) => {
            /* Call the SendVerificaitonMail() function when new user sign
            up and returns promise */
            this.SendVerificationMail();
            this.SetUserData(result.user);
            // tslint:disable-next-line: prefer-const
            // let emailVar = 'someEmail@gmail.com';
            const emailVar = result.user.email;
            // tslint:disable-next-line: prefer-const
            let uidVar = result.user.uid;
            const url = `/makeUser?email=${emailVar}&name=${uidVar}`;
            const t = await this.http.get<any>(environment.ngrockUrl + url).toPromise();
            window.alert(JSON.stringify(t));
          }).catch((error) => {
            window.alert(error.message);
          });
      }
```

The get function triggers on my server when the SignUp method is called on my website without a problem but when I try to stringify the response in my website(response received from the server) I get the following error message

```
Http failure response for https://2myUrl.ngrok.io/makeUser?email=richardTest@hotmail.com&name=JzVjey5xoXQNfi6oSVvyrDU05P52: 0 Unknown Error
```

So all I want to be able to do is to be able to ask the server for information and then receive it in n JSON format in my website. I tried POST methods but none of them seemed to work so I was hoping someone may be able to assist me. Thank you!

Comment: try `response.json({message: 'User registered'});` on your server

Comment: you should consider wrapping your `PerformQuery` function in a try-catch and logging out the issue.